# How to pivot 2 categorical columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a following example:

| Id | Name1 | Name2 | EstVal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Reve | Reve_1 | 100 |
| 2 | Reve | Reve_2 | 225 |
| 3 | Cost | Cost | 80 |
| 4 | Cost | Cost | 350 |

What I want to do is to `pivot` `Name1` column and one, particular value from `Name2` column (`Reve_2`). So the output should look like this:

| Id | Reve | Cost | Reve_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 80 | 225 |
| 2 | 225 | 350 | NULL |

I don't know how to use `pivot` in this case. I tried this:

```
SELECT Id, Reve, Cost, Reve_2
FROM #some_input_table
PIVOT (
MAX(EstVal)
FOR Name1 IN ([Reve], [Cost])) AS P

PIVOT (
MAX(EstVal)
FOR Name2 IN ([Reve_2]) AS P2
```

However, I can't use `EstVal` in `P2` pivot, since this value doesn't exist. How can I make it working?

Comment: is "Reve_1" in row 1 meant to be "Reve_2"?

Comment: No, Reve_2 is Reve_2, I don't want to take value of Reve_1 and don't want to pivot this value

Comment: Selectivley union the wanted data into 2 columns, then pivot that. First column has reve, reve_1, cost the second has the numbers.

Comment: Not sure this can be done. Please look here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ba853c2b4bf831599d7d8582f394d71  the problem is re-alignment of id 3 to id 1 and id 4 to id 2. What is **your** logic for that to occur?

Comment: I made some trick and duplicated `EstVal` column and named `EstValDupl`. Then in 1st pivot I call  `MAX(EstVal)` and in 2nd I call `MAX(EstValDupl)`. It solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. I did some trick - I duplicated values column `EstVal` and named it `EstValDupl`. Then in the 2nd pivot I use this column as a value and get the desired output of a table:

```
SELECT Id, Reve, Cost, Reve_2
FROM #some_input_table
PIVOT (
MAX(EstVal)
FOR Name1 IN ([Reve], [Cost])) AS P

PIVOT (
MAX(EstValDupl)
FOR Name2 IN ([Reve_2]) AS P2
```